# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with different shapes in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, cross-validation

I am trying to use `k-fold cross validation` and for this i needed to do accordingly with the training set.I implemented like below:

```
num_folds = 5
subset_size = num_training/num_folds
validation_accuracies = []

    for i in range(num_folds):
        Xcross_valid_set = X_train[i*subset_size:][:subset_size].shape
       # print X_train[:i*subset_size].shape,X_train[(i+1)*subset_size:]
        Xtrain_set = X_train[:i*subset_size] + X_train[(i+1)*subset_size:]
        #Xtrain_set=np.concatenate(X_train[:i*subset_size] , X_train[(i+1)*subset_size:])
        Ycross_valid_set=y_train[i*subset_size:][:subset_size]
        Ytrain_set=y_train[:i*subset_size]+y_train[(i+1)*subset_size:]
```

The problem is that shape of `X_train[:i*subset_size]` is **(0,3072)** and of `X_train[(i+1)*subset_size:]` is **(40000,3072)** in case of `i=0`.I have tried to use numpy.concatenate but didn't work.
**The result shape will be (40000,3072) here as the first term gives 0 row.So if the first term give (10,3072) and second term gives (30,3072) then the result shape will be (40,3072) i.e 40 rows. How can i merge the two different shaped into one training set??**

Comment: You should only index an array with one set of brackets: `X_train[i*subset_size:subset_size]`. What you you intend to do with the `+`? If you add numpy arrays, it adds their values, it does not concatenate them (like with lists). Please read: http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.concatenate` needs as first argument a list of arrays:

```
Xtrain_set = np.concatenate([X_train[:i*subset_size], X_train[(i+1)*subset_size:]])
```